# Autoresizing a tableview cell with a downloaded image and a multi line label

Tags: xcode, swift3, autolayout, interface-builder

I have tableview cells with an image view and a label.
The images are downloaded from a URL. They can be landscape or portrait which will determine their height constraint later on.
The label can be multiple lines and its lines property is set to 0, and the imageview is set to Aspect fill, in the attributes inspector.

I want to vertically resize the cells to fit the image and the label.

In cellForRow if I set the imageview's height constraint to something small like 100 then the image view covers the label. If I set it to 300 then it partially covers the label. And if I set it to something really high like 10000 it stretches the image but the label is not covered at all.

Here is the code:

```
class ArtistListViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 250
      }

    }

extension ArtistListViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ArtistTableViewCell
        cell.imageHeightConstraint.constant = 100
        let artist = artists[indexPath.row]
        cell.descriptionLabel.text = artist.description
        setupCellForImage(cell, artist: artist)
        return cell
    }

    fileprivate func setupCellForImage(_ cell: ArtistTableViewCell, artist: Artist) {
        let url = URL(string: artist.image)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                cell.artistImageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
            })
        }).resume()
    }
}
```

ImageView constraints:

```
Top space to superview = 0
Bottom space to description label = 20
Height = 235
```

Label constraints:

```
Bottom space to superview = 8
```

I have not changed priority of content hugging or compression resistance.

Here are 2 images where the height constraint is set to 300. While the images are loading and once finished loading:
[image]
[image]

What is going on here? Why is the cell not resizing according to the image view's height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ImageView, Attribute Inspector you need to select [Clip To Bounds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cL00a.png) . Then it will solve one part of your problem. Then you need to setup constraint correctly.